# C# Window Form Application, how to efficiently create a dynamic panel on a window form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, window

I would like to create a few panel dynamically in my window form application. Each panel will consist of 3 labels and one text box and one button. Now I know I can hard code this all at once by declaring each variable every time, but it takes a lot of coding and it is obviously not efficient at all.
So my question is: Is there a way to create pre-define panel dynamically where each time a panel is created will have a predefined layout setup already. So all i need to do is to add a panel, its location and size every time, and all the content(like labels, text-box and button) inside the panel are already setup with their location associated with the panel itself. Do I really have to create a class just for that?

Thanks in advance for read and taking your time.

Comment: You can create a user control and then add it dynamically to your form, may wanna see this as well http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Windows Forms control or user control, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Create a user control, and place on it whatever you like (your labels).  Expose public methods/properties of that control so you can control the contents of it.  Place as many of those on the form as you like, they will all look and behave same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example you can play with...

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    var panel1 = new Panel() { Size = new Size(90, 80), Location = new Point(10, i * 100), BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = i.ToString(), Location = new Point(10, 20) });
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = i.ToString(), Location = new Point(10, 40) });
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = i.ToString(), Location = new Point(10, 60) });
    Controls.Add(panel1);
}
```